# how to call awk on excel in perl

Tags: awk

I am trying to use variable or system command to call an awk (dealing with csv file)

the awk command is

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{if (\$6 == " ADMCHG") print \$0}' $output_dir/$userfile > $output_dir/$userfile.ADMCHG.
```

It works.

But, if I use variable or system command to call this awk command

```
$result = `awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{if ($6 == " ADMCHG") print $0}' "$output_dir/$userfile" > "$output_dir/$userfile.ADMCHG"`;
```

or

```
system ("awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{if (\$6 == " ADMCHG") print \$0}' $output_dir/$userfile > $output_dir/$userfile.ADMCHG");
```

I guess the problem is `awk -F "\"*,\"*" ,` how can I do to fix it?

[Using AWK on CSV Files](http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/using_awk_on_csv_files)

Comment: Awk on excel in perl.. what!?

Answer (score 1):

Once I ignored your confusing title, I think understood your problem -- you are failing to escape your quote marks, so your string is getting split up. A few things to consider:

- You can switch between `" and`', So for example:

  "this is a ' string with some ' single quotes in it" but
  "this is two " strings "with a word in between"
  BUT if you use double quotes, then [variables with a $ in front will be evaluated](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/contrasting-single-and-double-quotes-in-perl.html)
- You can use \ to escape things, so `" \" "` is one string. You can add

Most likely, you want single quotes:

```
system ('awk -F "\"*,\\"*" \'{if (\$6 == " ADMCHG") print \$0}\' $output_dir/$userfile > $output_dir/$userfile.ADMCHG');
```

Note that I have switched the quotes enclosing the string to single quotes, and escaped the 's using \ . I also escaped the literal \ with another \, which is why there is a `\\`.

Look [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?displaytype=print;node_id=401006) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi foobarbecue, Thank you for your answer. I tried it, it is not working. Can you give me more hints on this issue? And If I would like to use variable, how can I quote awk command in perl script?

Comment: Hi user, I didn't notice you wanted to have an actual \ in your system command. \ is an escape character in perl, so it disappears and preserves the character that comes after it as a literal character. I've edited my answer to reflect that. By the way, you can see I solved the string splitting problem by looking at the red vs black coloring.

Comment: User, did this solution work for you? If so, please accept it.